# Assign a variable into `g` once and only once for application in Flask

Tags: python, web, flask

I want to save an object which is the result of a expensive function.
The expensive function should only be processed once before any request.

I checked the document of Flask and considered about `g` for saving the result and `@app.before_first_request` decorator to define this assignment happended only once.

My codes are like this:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    g.rec = take_long_time_to_do()

@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    return render_template('index.html',var_rec=g.rec)
```

However, these codes won't work well. It works only in the first time `test` request is called. When I access "myapplication/test" second time, the `g.rec` doesn't exist, which will throw an exception

Does anyone have ideas about how to assign a global variable into `g` when initing the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g` is the global object for that request only.  Have you considered using a caching mechanism?

```
> pip search flask | grep "cache" | sort
Flask-Cache               - Adds cache support to your Flask application
Flask-Cache-PyLibMC       - PyLibMC cache for Flask-Cache, supports multiple operations
Flask-Memsessions         - A simple extension to drop in memcached session support for Flask.
```

Then you can store the result of `take_long_time_to_do()` there and retrieve it if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, sberry.  Can I use a global immutable object in that application? Why should I use `catching` instead of a global object?

Comment: Agreed - [`Flask-Cache`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Cache/) is pretty powerful, you can cache to memory/file/redis and set timeouts etc.

Comment: Check out the [caching other functions](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Cache/#caching-other-functions) example

Comment: @Firegun: no.  There is no global object available to all requests.  That is what the caching is for.

Comment: @sberry What do you mean `no global object available to all requests`? I can assign a global object after `app = Flask(__name__)` such as `rec=100` and then I can use this variable `rec` in any viewers function. Can't I?

Comment: Another option for caching would be [dogpile.cache](http://dogpilecache.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting that function call in `__init__.py` of your project package? I usually use `__init__.py` to initialize the `app = Flask(__name__)` etc. So lets say you can try the following:

```
# __init__.py:

from flask import Flask
from somemodule import take_long_time_to_do
app = Flask(__name__)
rec = take_long_time_to_do()
```

Then you can use the `rec` variable in any views as long as you import it:

```
# views.py

from myproject import rec
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    return render_template('index.html',var_rec=rec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Caching is the way to do it generally.  But assuming you have a one-off value and don't want to introduce caching infrastructure for some reason (value doesn't time out), you could also compute it at app startup as a module global, use it, and/or import it where needed.

If the value is needed in templates:

- Add it to templates via [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templating/#context-processors).
- Add it to the config module before app initialization.